# Composer install wp-plugin to vendor dir

Tags: wordpress, composer-php

I'm using Roots/Bedrock for my WordPress structure and I want to use WebDevStudios/CMB2 as a library and not as a plugin.

The Roots/Bedrock composer.json specifies that dependencies of `type:wordpress-plugin` be installed in `app/plugins`. The WebDevStudios/CMB2 composer.json declares that it is a `wordpress-plugin` type, so it gets installed into `app/plugins` which is not where I want it.

How can I get this dependency to be installed into `vendor` and not `app/plugins`?

I have a suspicion I might have to fork CMB2 and change it's type from `wordpress-plugin` to `library`, but I'm hoping there is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not using Roots/Bedrock but I had a similar problem when adding CMB2 as a dependency to a plugin (rather than loading it as a separate plugin).  It was installing the plugin in `wp-content/plugins` instead of `vendor`.  The following worked for me.

```
{
    "require": {
        "webdevstudios/cmb2": "^2.2",
    },
    "autoload"    : {
        "files": [
            "vendor/webdevstudios/cmb2/init.php"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "vendor/webdevstudios/cmb2": ["webdevstudios/cmb2"]
        }
    }
}
```

The key was the `installer-paths` entry that tells Composer where we want to install `webdevstudios/cmb2`.

I wrote a blog post about this at https://salferrarello.com/cmb2-composer-dependency/